# Configuring Eclipse tool to run a Windows command

Tags: eclipse

I would like to make a tool to run the following command in Eclipse. However, I haven't had success because "copy" is not a "Location" of a program, and so Eclipse doesn't recognize it.

```
copy /b ${env_var:SERVER_HOME}\pickup\star-web-custom.plan +,,
```

Any suggestions? I'm fairly new to Eclipse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- In "Location" put `${env_var:SystemRoot}\system32\cmd.exe`
- In "Arguments" put `/c "copy /b ${env_var:SERVER_HOME}\pickup\star-web-custom.plan +,,"`

It should help. If something goes wrong, then just try to play with "Arguments" as of something simple like `/c "somesimplecommandhere"`

Comment: This is the simplest method.  It's very clever.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put this command in a script and then set the location of that script (full path, including the full name of the script) in the "Location" text box.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually write this sort of thing as an Ant task instead of an External Tool configuration. That's not to say that you can't do it. One advantage of the Ant task is that it is more portable.